# Marketing Cloud Default Attribute Model vs Custom Attribute data model

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We at or client modifying the way of working in MC connected with Service Cloud. Instead of using import activities now we are planning to use SQL queries that extract the data from synchronized DE. We put this extracted data in DE which will be used into the journeys.

Now while setting up the journey, we are using decision splits where I have the below question and wanted to confirm the approach

1. Can we use the contact data > default attribute group created by connector having synchronized DE’s or
2. Should we create a replica of all sync DE and create a custom attribute group model in the journeys

After discussing it with couple of people working in Marketing cloud, everyone has there own thoughts around this and found option 2 is better due to it will avoid the instability of connector and help customer skip the step on the right moment. Please suggest to choose the correct option. Thanks

Comment: If you are planning to create a replica based on synched DE, then if there is a connector issue, both the synched DE and the replica DE will have the same "problem". In that case, don't bother creating a replica and use the system generated DEs.

Comment: To confirm another point, as per documentation we should not use the sync DE where as default attribute group consist of sync de. So do you still recommend the same solution.  Thanks you for your response so far

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer that - you can use one or the other or even a mix if needed - it all depends on the details of the journey that you’re building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been recorded issues when using the synchronized data extensions directly for certain tasks, such as [this filter example](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmiYQAS&title=filtered-data-extensions-created-from-synchronized-data-extensions-fail-when-using-2-or-more-fields-in-filter). I believe there is/was one specific to Journey Builder as well, but I couldn't find it.

This is likely where the difference in opinion is coming in; some people have run into issues like this before so they want the duplicate DE approach, while others have not encountered it so they don't see the point.

Personally I haven't run into any issues that would make it worthwhile to manage a duplicate DE over the synchronized DE directly (this will get a bit annoying when you need to add/remove fields), but others may have different experiences.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We had a discussion with Salesforce Architect and we got below response: 1) Create a custom attribute only in case of a complex journey where timing is very critical. 2) If one or more attribute is coming from another system that needs connection with salesforce. As said above by Anon, it might be overhead.